# How to call a class in another file?

Tags: python-3.x

I created a class within another file and I want to use it as an object in another file (I don't know if I'm using the right words, sorry. I haven't programmed in a few years).

The following code is the tube class that I've created:

```
class Tube:
    def __init__(self, inner_diameter, length):
        self.inner_diameter = inner_diameter
        self.length = length

    def getLength(self):
        return self.len

    def getInnerDiameter(self):
        return self.inner_dia
```

Then I called the following in another file:

```
import tube
tube1 = tube(0.18, 1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Am I doing something completely wrong? When I looked stuff up, I was getting something that I had to do a **call** function within my class to get it, but that didn't do anything. 
Sorry if this is a really obvious question, I am new to python and haven't coded in a quite a while and I only formally learned java.

Comment: Maybe tube.Tube(args)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of quick edits to your code:

```
class Tube:
    def __init__(self, inner_diameter, length):
        self.inner_diameter = inner_diameter
        self.length = length

    def getLength(self):
        return self.length       # rather than len

    def getInnerDiameter(self):
        return self.inner_diameter     # rather than inner_dia
```

then your statement to create an instance of tube:

```
import tube
tube1 = tube.Tube(0.18, 1)  # rather than Tube(0.18, 1)
```

This specifically calls the **init** method of the Tube class within the tube module (tube1 is an instance of a Tube from the tube module).

It's comparable to working with any other module. For example:

```
import math
print(math.pi)
```

... you need to specify the module before the method.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your class and `main.py` or the file you're calling `Tube.py` from, are in the same folder, you should have no problem doing this:

```
from tube import Tube
```

> I am new to python and haven't coded in a quite a while and I only
>   formally learned java

Now is a good time to learn how to do things in Python.

You can write properties instead of getters and setters like this:

```
from typing import final

@ final
class Tube:
    def __init__(self, inner_diameter, length):
        # Note the underscore, in Python this indicates the variable show be treated as 
        # private.

        # The : [int] and [float] are type hints.
        self._inner_diameter  : float = inner_diameter
        self._length : int = length

    @property
    def Length(self):
        return self.length

    @Length.setter
    def Length(self, value):
        self._length = value

    @property
    def getInnerDiameter(self):
        return self.inner_diameter

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Inner Diameter: {self._inner_diameter} Length: {self._length}"
```

Use it like this:

```
# Note: the keyword arguments.
obj = Tube(inner_diameter=0,length=1)
obj.Length = 5
print(obj.Length) # Calling the Length getter
# Calling the internal __str__
print(obj)
```

You can also declare a class [final](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.final).